# Custom Button - OnClick JavaScript - Reference Current Date?

Tags: javascript, administration, custom-button

I'm missing something simple here probably, but it's escaping me.

```
FormToUpdate.set("RETURNFUNDS_Sales_Rep_Signature_Date__c", {!today()} );
```

I've tried now() and today() above at the end, and it's failing.  What can I put in lieu of that to simply stamp that field with the current date?

**EDIT - Screenshot of error:**

[image]

**EDIT 2 for @techtrekker:**

[image]

**EDIT 3 - Solution Code (thanks @techtrekker for the assist)**

```
var padmonth = {!MONTH(TODAY())};
if( padmonth.toString().length == 1 ) { padmonth = '0'+padmonth } 
var padday = {!DAY(TODAY())};
if( padday.toString().length == 1 ) { padday = '0'+padday } 
   ........
FormToUpdate.set(  "RETURNFUNDS_Sales_Rep_Signature_Date__c"  , '{!YEAR(TODAY())}-' + padmonth + '-'+ padday  );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{!TODAY()}` will yield

> Wed Apr 10 00:00:00 GMT 2013

`{!NOW()}` will yield

> Wed Apr 10 20:07:18 GMT 2013

Neither of which will count as valid dates probably when passing to a webservice ?

```
{!DAY(TODAY())}/{!MONTH(TODAY())}/{!YEAR(TODAY())}
```

will yield

> 10/4/2013

Not a 100%, but you might also be able to leverage some Javascript Date Formatting functions.

Please try [YYYY-MM-DD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

```
{!YEAR(TODAY())}-{!MONTH(TODAY())}-{!DAY(TODAY())}
```

Just for display, you can also use

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd}">
        <apex:param value="{!TODAY()}" /> 
 </apex:outputText>
```

which renders

> 2013-04-10

Comment: FormToUpdate.set(  "RETURNFUNDS_Sales_Rep_Signature_Date__c"  , "{!DAY(TODAY())}/{!MONTH(TODAY())}/{!YEAR(TODAY())}" ); 
  --- without added quotes, same error.. WITH added quotes, new error (will add to Question).  Logical solution, but..  (?!)

Comment: Tried both double and single quotes, same error.

Comment: @AMM Added an edit - please try with YYYY-MM-DD format, which is likely the expected soap date format

Comment: Tried it.  Same error (with expected y/m/d reference).

Comment: I tried literal '2010/01/02' - I wonder if somehow it has to be made to a "date" type, if it doesn't like that it's a STRING being passed?!

Comment: I'd reckon its more YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD, I wonder if the 2013-4-10 needs padding to be 2013-04-10

Comment: AHH.  Yes.  '2010-01-02' worked fine... so it IS the padding.  Urgh. Is there a javascript zero-padding call??

Comment: Got it... added a "var padmonth = [ref]" then checked length and added "0" to front of it, and used it in the date.  Works like a charm.  Thanks, @techtrekker.